# Positoned header displays differently on mobile than desktop view with same length as the screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive

Positioned header displays at the top of the `div` on mobile, then the desktop view with same length screen displays in the center of the `div` like programmed. The problem only shows up on a mobile phone. Has anyone ran into a similar problem before?

Here are two screenshots, the first it how it looks on my mac in mobile view the second is on my phone

**Computer**:
[image]

**Mobile**:
[image]

```css
   

.overlay{
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.70;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #414A4C;
    z-index: 0;
}

 .page-banner-image{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:30%;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    max-height:800px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .page-banner-header{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color:#fff;
    display: table;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    }
   
   

 .page-banner-header .page-banner-header-table{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    }
   

 .page-banner-header .page-banner-text h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    }
 
   

 .page-banner-header .page-banner-text h3{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hero">
        <div id="owl-carousel-hero" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="page-banner-background">
                    <div class="page-banner-image" style="background-image:url('background.png');">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="page-banner-header wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=0.4s>
                    <div class="page-banner-header-table">
                        <div class="page-banner-text">
                            <h3>Sub Header</h3>
                            <h2>Main Header</h2>
                        </div>
              <!--           <div class="page-banner-btn">
                            <a class="hvr-grow transition" href="#"><?php //echo $btn ;?></a>
                        </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div><div class="overlay overlay-top"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by ' displays differently ' ? And please create a working snippet that replicates your problem,

Comment: on my mobile the header shows at the top of the div, but in a responsive view on my mac it shows in the center as supposed, and I will now. thank you for getting to my question

Comment: If you just paste some php code here, we cannot help you. Please instead paste the output html so you can recreate your problem here

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Did you run your code snippet ? Does the code provided replicate your problem ? As a suggestion, do not use `display:table` to center text vertically, but use `display:flex` with `justify-content:center`

Comment: Got the snippet working, thank you for your patience, and ooh that's interesting how come flex and not table ?

Comment: The snippet is working. What would be your desired result ? Meaning what's wrong with the snippet ? How would you want it to be instead? Also, `display:table` is considered a 'hack', an obsolete way of arranging items in a page. Flex is more, well, flexible and the way to go and the present/future in layouts. Plus tables can become a problem when dealing with widths, heights, margins etc. Search `display:table` downsides and you will see.

Comment: the desired result was to center align the header on a mobile, and adding flex fixed that problem now displays in the center. Thank you for your help!

Comment: glad i could help. Cheers :D